# OpenCV :: Seamless Cloning error

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I had a problem where I had an input image like this :

[image]

And I had to remove that sharp contrasting horizontal line in the image forehead as can been.

So tried blurring, filtering etc but nothing worked. So finally I used seamless cloning. And I got the result like this :

[image]

This pretty much solved my problem. But if you go through the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/cloning.html) and this [tutorial](http://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/), the parameters for seamless cloning is explained properly.

There we have a `srcImage` which is cloned to another `destinationImage`. For my problem, I took the srcImage as completely white and of the rectangle around the sharp line. (Below is the white image, hold the cursor around to see).

[image: Image below]

So my problem is how did this even work, as in any other image if I have instead of the white image it throws me a fatal error. Why did it work only with white image?

Comment: Did you see samples/cpp/cloning_demo.cpp example ?

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Yeah there also, the mask is a greyScaled mask with white area and black area.